# more elegant way to build and append lists?

Tags: python-3.5

I know this is a lame question but python newbie here. I came up with below and it works but I was wondering if there are more efficient ways to do this:

the goal here is calculate 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 - 4/11 .... n times

```
n = 5000
x = 1.0
list_1 = [] #make a list for denominator
list_2 = [] #make a list of fractions using list_1 as denominator
list_3 = [] #make a list change odd elements to negative

for i in range(n):
    list_1.append(float(x))
    x = x + 2
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    list_2.append(4/list_1[i])
for count, i in enumerate(list_2):
    if count % 2 == 0:
        list_3.append(i)
    else:
        list_3.append(i * -1)
sum(list_3)
```

Comment: You could easily combine all of the above into a single loop. Other than that, the code is fine.

Answer (score 3):

this would be a one-liner for your task:

```
s = sum((-1)**i * 4 / (2*i+1) for i in range(n))
```

it would be more efficient because no list is created (`.append` is never called); it just sums over a generator of all your elements.

if you really need the list of your elements (and not just the sum) you could construct it in a similar way:

```
lst = list((-1)**i * 4 / (2*i+1) for i in range(n))
```

Comment: You will want to make at least one of your numbers a float as in `sum((-1)**i * 4.0/ (2*i+1) for i in range(n))`, otherwise this won't give you the correct answer.

Comment: @steveb what would i win by doing that?

Comment: Run your code with `2` and then using `2.0`, you will see the answers are different as you are dividing 2 integers now (e.g. 1/3 = 0 but 1/3.0 = 0.33333).  This applies to Python 2.7x, 3x seems to be ok without using floats.

Comment: @steveb: the question is tagged `python-3.5`. [divison has changed in python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Comment: I just noticed, sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist That is awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do something like this, using a function:

```
def calc4DivX(n):
    signal = 1
    list_values = []
    for k in range(n):
        if signal == 1:
            list_values.append(4/n)
        else:
             list_values.append(-4/n)
        signal = signal*-1 # signal keeps alternating for every iteraction
     return sum(list_values)
#Call the function
print(calc4DivX(value))
```